# How to get selected item in list-group in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, list

I have a list-group like this:

```
<div class="list-group list">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active" id="leftOverlayTitle">
        Cras justo odio
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
</div>
```

I wonder how I can check with plain Javascript, which element is highlighted (selected).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to get the element which has an active class?

Comment: Try this - `$("div#list-group a.active").html()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get highlighted (active) items only:

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("list-group-item active");
```

To get all items and then do the checking with each separately:

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("list-group-item");
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
   if ((' ' + items[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' active ') > -1) 
       items[i].setAttribute('style', 'color: #F00');
   else 
       items[i].setAttribute('style', 'color: #CCC');
}
```

Either way, the key to solution is `getElementsByClassName` method. You can read more about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("list-group-item");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].onclick=function(){        
            console.log(this);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

let seleccionado= $(".list-group a.active").html()

let seleccionado = $("#ListaEnlaces a.active").html();

Comment: Is this related in any way to the question? This piece of what might be code needs some explanation to be considered a helpful answer.